# How to show only selected places tags on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to show selected places on google map. I have tried few things but it's not worked.

**below is my code**,

```
var map;
function initMap(lat, lng) 
  {
    lat = parseFloat(lat);
    lng = parseFloat(lng);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        'center'    : {'lat': parseFloat(lat), 'lng': parseFloat(lng)},
        'zoom'      : 15,
    'disableDefaultUI': false,
        'mapTypeId' : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          position:myCenter,
          icon:'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShhM5Gh9yzCVdoX_vTshfbfRQxFkXWkysxyXo2GtrBySldFejs5w'
      });
    marker.setMap(map);

     var request = {
        location: { lat, lng},
        radius: '50000',
        types: ['hospital','bus_station','travel_agency','subway_station','taxi_stand','doctor','dentist','bus_station','airport']
      };
      service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  }

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      console.log(" Places ", place);
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
  }
```

**As in code I have mention to show only places types** 
`['hospital','bus_station','travel_agency','subway_station','taxi_stand','doctor','dentist','bus_station','airport']`

**but it showing other places too like restaurants, hotels and much more as you can see in attached image**

> **How can I disable other places I want to populate only given places ?**

Thanks 
[image]